# Field Validation not working

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to `Java`. I have recently started my First project (Calculator) in Net beans.
While i was working on it I added a `if` condition to it.
The `if` condition checks whether the field is empty or not.

This is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    double a, b, c;
    a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    if(jTextField1.getText().equals("")) {
        jLabel2.setText("Please enter a number");
    }
    else {
        c = a + b;
        jLabel2.setText("" + c);
    }
}
```

When I click the button with empty field it give me an error like this:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at calc.jButton1ActionPerformed(calc.java:132)
    at calc.access$000(calc.java:11)
    at calc$1.actionPerformed(calc.java:53)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

But when i changed `if(jTextField1.getText().equals(""))` to `if(!jTextField1.getText().equals(""))` It worked correctly But when i add `else` condition to it The first part (Not == "") will work correctly. But second (else) will give error.

Please someone tell me how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your validation to occur before parsing the number:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int a, b, c;
    if(jTextField1.getText().equals("")) {
        jLabel2.setText("Please enter a number");
    }
    else {
        a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        c = a + b;
        jLabel2.setText("" + c);
    }
}
```

You may need also to check for other conditions, like is input a number. Putting text there will also throw NumberFormatException. I would change your validation logic to something like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int a, b, c;

    try {
       a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       jLabel2.setText("Please enter a number in field1");
       return;
    }

    try {
       b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       jLabel2.setText("Please enter a number in field2");
       return;
    }

    c = a + b;
    jLabel2.setText("" + c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no data then `jTextField1.getText()` will give you an empty string ("") and
`Integer.parseInt("")` with empty string will give you `NumberFormatException` because "" is not a valid number .plus you should check for both numbers so it should be like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    double a, b, c;
     if (jTextField1.getText().equals("") || jTextField2.getText().equals("")){
          jLabel2.setText("Missing Input");
     }else{
        try{
             a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
             b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
             c = a + b;
             jLabel2.setText("" + c);
          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
             jLabel2.setText("Enter Valid numbers");            
         }
    }
}
```

Simply put your code in `try` so in case if any input is not a valid number then control go to `catch` block and display the error

Answer (score 1):

You should surround your code with try and catch block. If the text fields are empty, you cannot parse their texts to integers.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int sum = 0;
    int a, b;
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        sum += a;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please correct your text field number 1");
    }       
    try {
        b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        sum += b;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please correct your text field number 2");
    }
    jLabel.setText("" + sum);
}
```